# Epi-week query/method for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

The definition for epi-week is the following:

"The first epi week of the year ends, by definition, on the first Saturday of January, as long as it falls at least four days into the month. Each epi week begins on a Sunday and ends on a Saturday."

Ref: [1](http://www.cmmcp.org/epiweek.htm)

I implemented them in server language (C#/Java) but my problem is to return a epi week and epi year from a SQL Server stored procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find EpiWeek:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EPIWeek] 
( 
    @Date SMALLDATETIME 
) 
RETURNS TINYINT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @EPIWeek TINYINT 

    --Fix first epi week (i.e if 0401 of year falls in first week, then it will give perfect start epiweek)
    SET @EPIWeek = DATEPART(WEEK,@Date)+1 - DATEPART(WEEK,RTRIM(YEAR(@Date))+'0104') 
    --if 0401 of year falls in second week, then change to epiweek of last year
    IF @EPIWeek = 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET @EPIWeek = dbo.EPIWeek(RTRIM(YEAR(@Date)-1)+'1231')
    END 

    --Fix last epi week (ie. If any date after 2812 falls below wednesday, then it is first epiweek of next year)
    IF MONTH(@Date) = 12 AND DAY(@Date)-DATEPART(DW,@Date) >= 28 
    BEGIN 
        SET @EPIWeek=1 
    END 

    RETURN(@EPIWeek) 
END
```

Find EpiYear:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EPIYear] 
( 
    @Date DATETIME
) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @EPIYear INT = DATEPART(YEAR, @Date);

  -- WHEN January 1-3 may belong to the previous year
  IF (DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE) = 1 AND dbo.EPIWeek(@DATE) > 50)
    SET @EPIYear = @EPIYear - 1;

  -- WHEN December 29-31 may belong to the next year
  IF (DATEPART(MONTH, @DATE) = 12 AND dbo.EPIWeek(@DATE) < 45)
    SET @EPIYear = @EPIYear + 1;

  RETURN @EPIYear;

END
```

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend to create a `Calendar` table in your database if you don't have it already.

It is a table that has a row for each day for the period long enough to cover your needs.

Add a column `EpiWeek` to such table and populate it once. Then use anywhere you need it instead of calculating it on the fly.

Calendar table is useful in many areas and helps to solve various problems using SQL set-based queries. Calendar table is a special case of `Numbers` table, which is also often useful.

For detailed example see:

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150512230546/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html)

This article has a section about ISO week number. I'm not sure if ISO Week and Epi Week are the same, but you can see an example how Aaron Bertrand calculated the ISO week number:

> Many, many, many people are dissatisfied with the way SQL Server calculates week number. Its strange algorithm used in `DATEPART(WEEK, <date>)` does not always yield the same number as the ISO standard, which dictates that week 1 is the first week with 4 days. To deal with that, we can borrow from Books Online and create the following function:
>
> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ISOWeek 
> ( 
>     @dt SMALLDATETIME 
> ) 
> RETURNS TINYINT 
> AS 
> BEGIN 
>     DECLARE @ISOweek TINYINT 
>
>     SET @ISOweek = DATEPART(WEEK,@dt)+1 
>         -DATEPART(WEEK,RTRIM(YEAR(@dt))+'0104') 
>
>     IF @ISOweek = 0 
>     BEGIN 
>         SET @ISOweek = dbo.ISOweek 
>         ( 
>             RTRIM(YEAR(@dt)-1)+'12'+RTRIM(24+DAY(@dt)) 
>         ) + 1 
>     END 
>
>     IF MONTH(@dt) = 12 AND DAY(@dt)-DATEPART(DW,@dt) >= 28 
>     BEGIN 
>         SET @ISOweek=1 
>     END 
>
>     RETURN(@ISOweek) 
> END 
> GO
> ```
>
> Then we can update the table:
>
> ```
> UPDATE Calendar SET W = dbo.ISOWeek(dt)
> ```

Also, here are few links about Numbers table:

[You REQUIRE a Numbers table!](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

[Generate a set or sequence without loops](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)

Comment: We can optimize the isoweek=0 condition part as:
--Just set the epiweek of last date of last year
IF ISOweek = 0 
    BEGIN 
        SET ISOweek = dbo.ISOweek 
        ( 
            RTRIM(YEAR(dt)-1)+'1231'
        )
    END

Comment: Also, we need to update the epiyear by some additional logic (probably you may still argue it is not the part of this SO question) because if the week is changed but year still shows the same year (So the changed epiweek should be of another year)

Comment: @Aarush, my point was to show you the approach, so that you could adjust it to your needs. I'm glad that you found my answer useful.